# Hamburger menu on desktop and "bottom navigation" on mobile

Tags: consistency

I was once told that i should avoid making the user relearn the UI/GUI, but i think that to my next project, it'll be better if i use a hamburger menu on the desktop/large screen version and a [bottom navigation](https://uxplanet.org/perfect-bottom-navigation-for-mobile-app-effabbb98c0f?gi=9980d121c709) on the mobile screen version of the website.

Is that a bad idea? Why?

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a broad question, but no, having a tab bar/bottom navigation for mobile and a hamburger for desktop is not inherently bad UX.

**The key is to use strong design patterns.**

Mobile and desktop serve a different purpose and have a different style of use. 
Comfortable thumb reach and limited screen estate are simply issues that desktop designs don't have to keep in mind that strongly. Therefore, different UX is actually desired for different screen sizes. By using design patterns, you avoid having to teach your users new behaviours and expectations, regardless if your desktop and mobile designs are slightly different from one another.

Answer (score -1):

The bottom navigation bar enables quick movement from deep in one topic to the top of another topic. Keep it available as the user descends the hierarchy, either by showing it persistently, or by concealing and revealing it upon scroll.

The bottom navigation bar shouldn’t be used for:

- Views focused on a single task, such as an email “Compose” screen
- Views containing user preferences or settings

[Additionally you would like to check this out.](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#) It is a guideline for material Design but helps you by giving tips on Usage and Behavior on different devices.